# ScrollMagic - progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollmagic

I'm using the scrollMagic library on a site that I need to display a progress bar. The bar will show the users' location on the page. The width of the progress bar will simply change as the user scrolls up or down. I can't seem to get it to work with the scrollMagic library. This is what I tried among other things. Thanks!

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
$(function progressBar() {
  var tween = TweenMax.fromTo("#progress", 1, {
    width: "0%"
  }, {
    width: "100%"
  });
  var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: ".header-wrap",
      duration: "100%"
    })
    .setTween(tween)
    .addTo(controller);
});
```

Comment: Do you get any error in the console?

Answer (score 3):

Took me some time to figure out, hope it helps someone who is looking out for solution.

You will have to use the progress method of scroll magic.

```
.on("progress", function(e) {
    var progressvalue = Math.floor(100 * e.progress);
    $('.scroll-progress').css('width',progressvalue +"%");
})
```

Here is the whole code, how it looks

```
var pin = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerHook: "onLeave",
    duration: "1100%",
    triggerElement: "#pin"
})
.setPin("#pin")
.setTween(tl)
.setClassToggle("#pin", "active")
// Add this code
.on("progress", function(e) {
    var progressvalue = Math.floor(100 * e.progress);
    $('.scroll-progress').css('width', progressvalue + "%");
})
.addTo(controller);
```

In html add a div where you want to show progress.

```
<div class="scroll-progress" style="width:0%; height:5px; background:#0090c6; position:fixed; bottom:0; left:0; z-index:9999"></div>
```

Comment: hi, I've been trying to make this progressbar to work on a scene with multiple  pinned sections without luck.
https://jsfiddle.net/o0hy1mLs/1/ could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much this will help you, but you should try the 'mousewheel' event:

```
window.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e){
wDelta = e.wheelDelta < 0 ? false : true;
if(wDelta)
    <mousewheel goes up>
else
    <mousewheel goes down>
});
```

or there is even an onscroll attribute if you don't care which direction the user scrolls:

```
<body onscroll="doStuff()">
```

[More info for onscroll](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onscroll.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this before using the scrollMagic Library. I simply placed "$('.progressBar').css("width","+=1%")" inside the if and "$('.progressBar').css("width","-=1%")" inside the else. The issue with it is that depending on how fast I scroll, the javascript will render the animation differently each time and the progress bar reaches the end before I get to the bottom of the page :(

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you want to make a progress bar in the header? I have the div.page that contains whole page. And in my header i have a div.header__progress

```
let progressTween = new TimelineMax()
.to('.header__progress', 1, {
  width: '100%'
});

let progressScroll = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: '.page',
  triggerHook: 0,
  duration: '100%'
})
.setTween(progressTween)
// .addIndicators()
.addTo(controller);
```